# Multiple image upload with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

How to upload multiple images to the web server with single button.I know there are couple of options available like flash,j query and silverlight.The problem is that there are many others things I want to do with images like upload the same image with different size (thumbnail) and want to change the image file name something like a GUID and want to store the path in database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload multiple images in one shot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152746/upload-multiple-images-in-one-shot)

Comment: But I want some more functionality needed as mention in the question.

Comment: You ask for a mini project here, this is not a question. You must made that by your self and come back where you have been stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use uploadify.js for the same.

- It is light weight as it contains jquery code.
- Easy to implement.

Here is the link for the same. [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

Comment: I've made good use of Uploadify too, combined with http://imageresizing.net/ to generate the thumbnail image.